# How to make eyelids that close with a shape key?

Tags: shape-keys

My character is a cartoon so his eyes are larger than normal. I can make the shape key to close the eye but on the way down or up the eyeball penetrates through the eyelid. Is there no way to fix this without making two shape keys?

This is what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Please show an image of your Blender 3D View to illustrate and clarify.

Comment: There you go. I fixed that but had to make three shape keys to close the eye. I guess that wouldn't be so bad if I could control them all with one slider.

Answer (score 3):

If you made a second shape key to "fix" it, you can use a Blend Key without the need to manipulate multiple keys.

In the shapekey dropdown, next to the min/max setting, deselect "Base" and select the key you want to blend with the current key.

Imagine it like parenting key1 to key2, it will blend the two shapes when you use Key2.

The problem in your case seems to be that the eyelid has very little geometry compared to the eye, so the shape key interpolates it linearly along the edges which intersect the eye.

A fix would be to increase geometry to adjust it to the eye and it should work fine if it has more steps in-between.

Comment: Yeah I figured I need to add more geometry but I'm following a book so I wanted to keep the geometry the same. I had it set up like you said. The first key uses the basis as the relative key, the second one uses the first key, and the third one uses the second key (yeah I made three). But to get the eye to close I have to put them all at 1. Is there a way to create a slider or something for all three at once?

Comment: Yes. You can do this via Drivers. 
Here is a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4qYHNA_x4Q
Its pretty simple to use. The principle is to use an object to as a controller for the shape key(s). In your case, you just need to use the same object for all shape keys. So when you move the driver all shape keys get affected.

Comment: What I really need is one driver that moves the first key from 0 to 1, then when the first one has reached 1 it moves the second from 0 to 1, etc. Is that also possible? I don't know how. I was able to get them all to move with one driver but what all of them moving to 1 at the same time does not give me the results I want. I'll make another question. Thank you.